# How do java9 compact strings dealing with serialization?

Tags: java, string, serialization, binary-serialization

I am quite familiar with java, but somehow serialization was always beyond my responsibilities.

Java9 introduced [compact strings feature](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254), so characters in strings are always backed into `byte[]`, not `char[]` array. This is quite good from memory perspective, allowing Latin1 strings to occupy (roughly) x2 less memory. Nevertheless, this is kinda unclear for me from serialization perspective. Let me explain:

Let us have a serializable class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    public String name;
    public String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Now if we'll serialize the created person into binary (I won't copy-paste the code, but [this is how it is usually being done](http://mrbool.com/differences-between-binary-serialization-and-serialization-in-java/31208), we'll have either binary file or byte array.

Now, the question: If we'll have a `new Person("John", "Doe")` and a `new Person("Jön", "Döe")` being serialized using java9+, will they be correctly deserialized in earlier releases of java (let's say java8)? How could java handle it if can? Thanks.

Comment: The in-memory format of a string does not dictate the serialized form of the string. I can't say for sure, but my guess is: Yeah, not a problem. :-)

Comment: According to the specification of the [Java Object Serialization protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#53801), strings are always serialized into UTF-8. This specification has not been changed for Java 9